# A program for polytime languages

Tags: computability, polynomial-time, enumeration

Does their exist a program  P[m,s] which always halts and for any polytime language exists an m; possibly incomputable; such that P[m,s] accepts only those strings s which are in the language.

Comment: What do you think? We don't answer problem dumps here. We expect you to make some effort on your own first.

Comment: Hi @Yuval... If we take m as incomputable the such a program seems feasable...but how does one prove it.

Comment: Well, one spends some time thinking about the exercise, and makes gradual progress, until hopefully eventually solving it completely.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Let $m$ code both a Turing machine for the language and a polynomial time bound on its running time.